# Connecting a macbook pro to an external display

Tags: hdmi, external-display, macbook-pro-retina

I just ordered a 13" macbook pro w/ retina and a 1920x1080 AOC (2436VH) external monitor. What setup will give me the best resolution on the external? mini display port to HDMI?  I'd like to use the rMBP monitor and the external monitor separately (individual displays).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the technical specifications on [this page](http://us.aoc.com/monitor_displays/2436vh), your monitor has VGA and HDMI input. Both of those will work with the full 1920x1080 resolution of your monitor. HDMI *might*, but is not guaranteed to, have a somewhat superior video quality due to being digital rather than analog like VGA.

Additionally, HDMI supports audio in-line whereas VGA does not. The monitor your mentioned has built-in speakers so you might consider HDMI superior for that reason as well.

Comment: Thanks I wasn't sure if there would be much difference. I'll go with the hdmi.